# How to Create a Standalone Autocomplete Form using Google Sheets Data

Tags: javascript, json, forms, google-sheets

I have a (live) spreadsheet in Google Sheets containing street addresses and days of the week.

Here is some example data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jeXo1SPNPn1AG4XvnVozEjoS_bdnzjYUa47w2lDSk64/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Here is the data as JSON: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1jeXo1SPNPn1AG4XvnVozEjoS_bdnzjYUa47w2lDSk64/default/public/values?alt=json

I want to create a form where the user types in their street address which is then matched to the corresponding day of the week. Ideally the street address would autocomplete with valid (partial matching) street addresses.

The form needs to work on 3 different websites, on three different domains, running 3 different CMSs.

I am trying to work out the best way I can create a standalone form that can be embedded as either an iframe or HTML/javascript in each of the different websites.

The form could be coded on a separate website which rerouted the JSON through the same domain as the form. However this would require setting up another website/ web app/ SSH certificate.

Is it possible to create a standalone form as required inside the Google ecosystem that can be embedded in other websites?

What is the best way to create a standalone autocomplete form using JSON from Google Sheets?